# Video is delayed when recording

Tags: audio, video, recording

I need to record my screen. I have tried different recording softwares, but I always have the same issue: the recording of the video is delayed with respect to the audio (so I hear the audio before seeing the part of video related to that sound). As I said, I tried different softwares (OBS, Kazam, SimpleScreenRecorder, ...) but the issue remains so it is not related to the software used. 
 I read some solutions that suggested to add a delay in the encoding, but this will not work for me: in my case, the delay is not constant, but it increases throughout the recording. 
 Any suggestion? 
 **OS**: Linux Mint 20.02 Cinnamon 
 **Cinnamon Version**: 5.0.6 
 **Kernel version**: 5.4.0-89-generic

Comment: Have you tried lowering encoding complexity? I.e. use libx264 ultrafast preset?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov in the OBS settings I can choose between "x264" and "x264 low CPU usage preset, increases size file"...do you mean the second one? Cause I already tried with x264. If yuo mean somenthing else, please tell me how to do because I don't know

Comment: Have you tried just shifting the audio in whatever tool you're using to view the video? In vlc, you can do this with the J and K keys.

Comment: @terdon as I said in the question, the delay is not constant...I may shift the audio, but after 10 minutes it is again not synchronized with the video

Comment: Yeah, I'm just wondering if maybe the problem is in the player and not the recording. I have recently used both Kazam and SimpleScreenRecorder and had no issues with the sound/video timing.

Comment: @terdon mmm nope, I tried with two other players but issue remains

Comment: *"do you mean the second one?"* Yes.